# Laravel error: NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161 (resource)

Tags: php, laravel

**If I use the below method, it works fine.**

```
Route::get('create', function () {
    return view('post.create');
});
```

**However, if I use the resource, it gives me the below errors:**

`Route::resource('posts', 'PostController');`

**It gives the below error**

> NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `Route::resource('posts', 'PostController');` generates

```
Route::get('posts/create', 'PostController@create');
```

NOT

```
Route::get('create', 'PostController@create');
```

This means you have to link to 'post/create'

```
<a href="/posts/create">New Post</a>
```

Comment: If my answer helped you, please mark it as the answer, so your question appears are solved. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create the Post using Resource Controller.
Your URL or Route should be `posts/create` and not `posts` because `posts` is used to get the List of the posts which will fire `index` method from your Resource Controller.
To Create, your Route must be `posts/create` and it will file `create` method from your Resource Controller.
It means,

```
Route::resource('posts','PostsController'); => Route::get('posts','PostsController@index);
```

AND

```
Route::resource('posts/create','PostsController'); => Route::get('posts/create','PostsController@create);
```

Let me know if that works!